# Swap on SSD or HDD and how much?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, swap

***Before I start I am a Linux noob.***

I will be running Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my 120Gb Kingston SSD. (Just the system files for windows and Ubuntu). Because of the space limitations I do not want to use 32GB of the SSD for swap. My plan was to use something between 8 and 16GB of swap. (I have 16GB of RAM). What would you guys recommend?

Comment: For hybernate to function you should have at leat as much SWAP as RAM. More than 16GB is not needed.

Comment: I think the real question is "do you need swap with 16GB of RAM". What are you using your computer for?

Comment: I am going to move to Linux from windows, i mainly use the system for games, (So Eu4, FM16 , Witcher3, CSGO,)
, but i am going to dual boot windows so i can play the Windows exclusives ( Fallout 4)

Answer (score 0):

Swap should be on SSD or else it might slow down your system when it will be needed (used to happened to me when I was using virtualbox so I have reduced swappiness from 60 to 10 to solve this)
If you want to use hibernation then you will need at least 20GB as shown here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq.
If you don't use hibernation then with 16GB ram you should be ok with a small swap, so use around 4GB in order to get more space.